# How can you put a tkinter scale number into txt file?

Tags: python, file, tkinter

I'm trying to put the number from the scale into a txt file. 
But getting an error. The code i pasted is in a class, just posting the relevant information.

Putting the command into the write part of pythons built in file manipulation.

```py
self.spawnrate_scale = Scale(from_=10, to=2000, orient=HORIZONTAL, label="Spawn Rate",)
self.spawnrate_scale.grid(row=0, column=1)

self.spawnrate_button = Button(text="Apply", command=self.spawnsetting)
self.spawnrate_button.grid(row=1, column=1)


spawnfile = open("carspawnspeed","w")
spawnfile.write(self.spawnrate_scale.get())
spawnfile.close()
```

```
spawnfile.write(self.spawnrate_scale.get())
```

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int

Comment: try spawnfile.write(str(self.spawnrate_scale.get())) ?!

Comment: Nope sorry, it doesn't print anything into the file. EDIT: Ignore this comment, it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Than post your answer and close the task ?!

Comment: I don't really know how to use this sorry..

Comment: @PentaKill you should put your comment as answer.

Comment: Yeah, was you after all. Not me.

Comment: you can mention PentaKill in your answer

Comment: Ah, ok, will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
self.spawnfile.write(self.spawnrate_scale.get())
```

to

```
self.spawnfile.write(str(self.spawnrate_scale.get()))
```

fixed it.